# How to export each layer as GIF in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have multiple video layers on photoshop (imported as png sequences). I need to export each layer as GIFs. I can do this one by one using ctrl+alt+shift+s and selecting GIF. But there are multiple files and it takes too long to export one by one. Is there a way to automate this ?
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the **Layers** panel.
2. Select all the layers you want to save as image assets.
3. Right-click your selection and select **Export As** from the context menu.
4. Change format to **GIF**.
5. Click **Export**.
6. Choose a destination folder and export the images.

You could also potentially automate this series of actions using PhotoShop Actions. From the main menu, select **Window > Actions** to expose the Actions panel which you can use to record and replay your steps on subsequent files. After recording you can also edit the steps to refine your recorded Action further if necessary.

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work for video layers in photoshop. Only works for image layers